# Using wheelDelta in onmousewheel event via Script#

Tags: c#, javascript, mouseevent, mousewheel, script#

I use mouse events in Script# with `ElementEvent` argument.
But I can not find `WheelDelta` property in this argument for `onmousewheel` event.
How is it possible to use this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by introducing following type and method (using Script# 0.7.5):

```
[Imported]
public static class Global
{
    [IntrinsicProperty, ScriptAlias("e.wheelDelta")]
    public static int WheelDelta
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}
```

And in `onmousewheel` event I just paste `Global.WheelDelta` where I wanna access to wheelDelta.

For more latest releases of Script# (>= 0.8) one should replace `Imported` with `ScriptImport` and `IntrinsicProperty` with `ScriptField`.

Comment: I'd say thats a reasonable stop-gap solution. Real solution would be to update the ElementEvent (or potentially a new derived MouseEvent class) itself to include the property in the first place... and then submit a pull request.

Comment: @NikhilK, I understand. I'll submit a pull request later.